# Sending an Email with python using the SMTP Library

Tags: python, email, smtp

```
import smtplib

def prompt(prompt):
    return raw_input(prompt).strip()

fromaddr = prompt("From: ")
toaddrs  = prompt("To: ").split()
print "Enter message, end with ^D (Unix) or ^Z (Windows):"


msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\n\r\n"
       % (fromaddr, ", ".join(toaddrs)))
while 1:
    try:
        line = raw_input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    if not line:
       break
    msg = msg + line

    print "Message length is " + repr(len(msg))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com:25')
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

I'm trying to send an Email using that example, but it doesnt work, I dont get any error it just doesn't send anything, I'm trying to send it to a hotmail email. Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Your indentation suggests that server = .. is in while loop. I guess that is not what you intended.

Comment: sorry about that, I fixed the Identation.

Comment: Does your server require authentication? Does it fail silently if it doesn't get it?

Comment: I dont have a server, the server I want to send the message to is hotmail which is smtp.live.com:25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `smtplib.SMTP()` uses invalid arguments. According to the smtplib docs:

> SMTP([host[, port[, local_hostname[,
>   timeout]]]])

So, the `SMTP` constructor takes the optional arguments for hostname, port etc. But you've passed port and hostname as one argument (`server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com:25')`).

Provided you have everything else right, if you change that line to read `server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com', 25)`.

If your server requires authentication (and I suspect it does), before you actually send the email you'll want to call `server.login(user, password)` to login so you can actually send the message.